# Does exist a free software that gives you Entity-Relation Diagram from a SQL file?

Tags: sql, ddl, erd

I have a .sql file representing my phpmyadmin database. I want to see the entity relation diagram of it. Does exist an easy and free software that shows it from a SQL file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could MySQL workbench : http://wb.mysql.com/

As I understand, it allows you to reverse engineer the diagram from the SQL

Comment: Much like human relationships, entity relationships are never simple.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself and the last update was in 2009, but maybe it helps in your case: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sql2diagram/

Comment: i download it and the zip only contains 3 dll files and one exe file.... when i start the exe file nothing happens :S

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. To do something useful with a DB dump, you need to load it into a DB first. All analyzers that I know of connect to a database and then do their magic; if they did it differently, they would need to learn each DB dump format, then import that into an internal database for analysis. Why complicated when you can do it simple?

For free ER analysis, there are many options. Any decent DB admin tool can do it.